# How to modify the gemfile? (marshal data too short)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-4, redmine

I'm trying to install rails but I get a "marshal data too short" error. I read in this question ( [bundle update fails : marshal data too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786630/bundle-update-fails-marshal-data-too-short) ) that I can update the Gemfile to make it work.

My problem is that I really have no idea how to modify this "Gemfile".

Thx.

Comment: Gemfile is a file that exists (notice case) in the root of the project, it's plain text and can be edited with any text editor.  However, it may have nothing to do with your problem.  When are you seeing the error?

Comment: Here is the command line: `gem install rails` and this is what I get: `error while executing gem ... (argumenterror) marshal data too short`

Comment: Are you using rvm?  And are you following a tutorial?

Comment: No I am not using rvm. I am following this tutorial: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/InstallRedmineOnDebianStableApacheMysqlPassenger 
Step 1.6

Comment: @trh Where is the gemfile located on MacOX? I'm looking it for different issue.

Comment: @D09r - its in the root of your rails project  - so if you create an app called good_times, then the file will be in good_times/Gemfile -- it's the same for all platforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn, it was so simple... to update the gemfile, you only got to execute these two command lines:

```
gem source -r https://rubygems.org/
gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
```

Then you can execute your installation normally:

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: While this explains the specific case of the asker, it does not technically answer the question; "How does one edit a gemfile?" - google lead me here with that question, because I also need to edit a gemfile for a different installation problem. Could someone edit the answer to also explain where to find the "gemfile" for an installation?

Comment: Could someone tell me where the gemfile is located?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root of your application, and look for Gemfile. The root of the application is where you run rails server from, in case you were wondering :)

Open Gemfile using your favorite text editor, and try changing the rubygems source from HTTP to HTTPS.

Locate the following:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Replace it with:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

You might want to check out this thread: [Marshal data too short](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2015#issuecomment-13419027)

Comment: Thx for the answser but the problem is I have no rails running since I am trying to install it.

Comment: Ok, then you should look at some docs and try setting up! I had blogged about it once - it's a little too specific, but just in case it helps, look at http://thirstyforcola.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/setting-up-glittergallery/

Comment: BTW, if your only problem is getting rails to work and you've set up everything else correctly, make the changes I suggested, and do a `gem install rails`. Then run a `bundle install`. To see that it works good, `rails s`